# PHP - Get Custom Headers when Using Nginx with php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, fpm

I'm trying to convert my PHP web application (a RESTful API) from Apache to Nginx.

It's working fine in Apache, but the codebase currently uses the `apache_request_headers()` method in order to retrieve the **custom** headers that we use for authentication. An example header is `auth_system_signature`.

I had hoped it would be a simple case of replacing the call to that function  with [getallheaders()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php). However, it appears that [this method is undefined when using php-fpm](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62596).

I see various ["workarounds" on the net](https://www.popmartian.com/tipsntricks/2015/07/14/howto-use-php-getallheaders-under-fastcgi-php-fpm-nginx-etc/) that will define the function if it doesn't exist, but they all appear to loop over `$_SERVER` which does not have my custom headers. I'm pretty sure if it did, then we wouldn't have been using `apache_request_headers()` in the first place.

Is there a way to retrieve the custom headers in the request with php-fpm, or do I just have to move over to using `php-cgi`?

### Context

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- PHP version: 7.0.

Comment: Are you sure that your custom headers are not present in *$_SERVER* ? Maybe [this from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/403728/nginx-php-fpm-and-custom-header) is close to your question?

Comment: I think your onto something there. Following the links through I found: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers which I will now try

Comment: Ok, if I add `underscores_in_headers on` to my nginx.conf then the headers will appear in the $_SERVER superglobal with `HTTP_` prefix which is good enough for me. The stackoverflow link you posted suggested replacing underscores with hyphens but this is a better solution IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Nginx won't pass on headers that have underscores in them by default. You could replace your custom headers' underscores with hyphens [as others have done](https://serverfault.com/questions/403728/nginx-php-fpm-and-custom-header), or you could [update your nginx.conf file](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) and set:

```
underscores_in_headers on
```

Now your headers will appear in the `$_SERVER` superglobal with the `HTTP_` prefix. They will also be in all caps.

Comment: Sorry, I've should have known better!